# How to finish an activity, onbackpressed when you have a pop up inflated

Tags: java, android

For the app i'm currently building i inflate a popup on the activity if there is no internet connection, the problem is that if the user presses their phone's back button, the popup disappears but u still get to see the activity without any information.
I would like to find out a way to finish the activity as well, when the back button is pressed.
Heres the code for the popup im currently inflating:

```
public void connection_error(final Class<?> clss){
        if(!Functions.isOnline(getApplicationContext())) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_nointernet, null);

            int width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            int height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            boolean focusable = true; // lets taps outside the popup also dismiss it
            final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, width, height, focusable);

            popupWindow.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

            Button btn_retry = popupView.findViewById(R.id.btn_retry);
            btn_retry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (Functions.isOnline(getApplicationContext())) {
                        finish();
                        popupWindow.dismiss();
                        launchActivity(clss);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.label_no_internet), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: u want to close the pop up as well as the app when user click on back button right?? Also, wat is the function launchActivity(clss); doing ? show the code of it as well

Comment: I want to close the pop up as well as the current activity, i do not wish to close the app ,launchActivity, is a simple function that just does an intent of the class i sent (so if i have launchActivity(MainActivity.class) it will do an intent of the MainActivity).

Comment: u wnat to close the activity and start which activty?

Comment: The same. The reason why i wanna close it is cause the information within each activity comes from a database, therefore i need to close the current activity with no information, and open it again so its loads the neccessary information

Answer (score 0):

Set a boolean that's set to true if your popup is open. Something like,

`boolean popUpOpen = true;`

Override the onBackPressed Method:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
     if(popUpOpen){
       super.onBackPressed(); // Closes Popup.
     }
     super.onBackPressed(); // Normal Behaviour - Finishes Activity if popup is open
}
```